# Keploy integration with springboot application

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, redis, rabbitmq

I am trying to integrate Keploy with spring boot application. Our application uses Redis, mongo, Rabbit MQ, Liquibase. I am using keploy version 1.1.5 and able to start the application. But when I am trying to access the end point I am getting the below error.

```
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.keploy.grpc.stubs.Service.access$35500()Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$Descriptor;
```

Below are the dependencies our project is using.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
   <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to use upgrade to latest keploy version but getting different exception while making the application up.

Answer (score 1):

Keploy doesn’t support the redis version you are using. Use 2.9.3 if possible. Also the Java-SDK of Keploy doesn’t work with Java 17 nor 19.